Ridiculous VMEM usage when using Ray on a cluster
Initial Problem:
I am testing out a multiprocessing Python package called Ray to parallelise my code. Original code works fine on my laptop, core-i7-13800H, 32GB RAM. When running on a local cluster however, the job fails when I specify num_cpus (a Ray keyword) greater than 40, despite having requested 50 CPUs and 200GB of RAM from the cluster. For reference, I was using num_cpus=18 on my laptop. STDOUT returns a huge blurb that I think may be an OOM error (see below).
> ^[[36m(func_parallel pid=70267)^[[0m [2024-11-01 10:33:28,278 E 70267 75787] logging.cc:108: Unhandled exception: N5boost10wrapexceptINS_6system12system_errorEEE. what(): thread: Resource temporarily unavailable [system:11]
> ^[[36m(func_parallel pid=70115)^[[0m OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 1 of 50: Resource temporarily unavailable
> ^[[36m(func_parallel pid=70115)^[[0m OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 16384 current, 16384 max
> ^[[36m(func_parallel pid=69306)^[[0m 2024-11-01 10:33:29.811669: F external/local_tsl/tsl/platform/default/env.cc:74] Check failed: ret == 0 (11 vs. 0)Thread tf_numa_-1_Eigen creation via pthread_create() failed.
> ^[[36m(func_parallel pid=69306)^[[0m *** SIGABRT received at time=1730482409 on cpu 55 ***
> ^[[36m(func_parallel pid=69306)^[[0m PC: @     0x14a9fbfa8cbb  (unknown)  raise
> ^[[36m(func_parallel pid=69306)^[[0m     @     0x14a9fcabc8c0  186786352  (unknown)
> ^[[33m(raylet)^[[0m A worker died or was killed while executing a task by an unexpected system error. To troubleshoot the problem, check the logs for the dead worker. RayTask ID: 4e9c3bd9b738a771af2ce9c4f66013ce9dbb521201000000 Worker ID: 52b96fe61ede380cde1d513fc65c222ba65a0100a2a1a8b00ad8f310 Node ID: ea8ebb2f21de741cf396d92301075881372f10000e39b7518e080cbb Worker IP address:  Worker port: Worker PID: Worker exit type: SYSTEM_ERROR Worker exit detail: Worker unexpectedly exits with a connection error code 2. End of file. There are some potential root causes. (1) The process is killed by SIGKILL by OOM killer due to high memory usage. (2) ray stop --force is called. (3) The worker is crashed unexpectedly due to SIGSEGV or other unexpected errors.

Running top shows that RES per core is only 1.5GB, but a whopping 92GB VMEM per core, resulting in over 2TB of VMEM total usage for the job! There isn't anything in the code that warrants such high usage.
I cannot share the original code, but I tested a simplified code to check if there is a memory leak and to reproduce this without all the other module imports and data preprocessing.
Simplified Problem:
The simplified code is shown below where the parallelised function takes in a 10000x10000 matrix, multiplies it with itself, sums all elements, adds it in a loop, and outputs the summed result. I tried using the Python Multiprocessing package, Ray Core, and Ray Multiprocessing Pool.
import os
os.environ['RAY_DEDUP_LOGS'] = '0'
import numpy as np
import ray
from ray.util.multiprocessing import Pool

# Used by Ray Core
@ray.remote
def func_parallel(db):
    a = 0
    for _ in range(5):
        a = a + np.sum(np.matmul(db, db))

    print(a)
    return a

# Used by Ray Multiprocessing Pool
# def func_parallel(db):
#     a = 0
#     for _ in range(5):
#         a = a + np.sum(np.matmul(db, db))

#     print(a)
#     return a

nloop = 50
mat = np.ones((10000, 10000))

# Tested with Ray Core
ray.init(num_cpus=40, object_store_memory=80*1024*1024)
db_ref = ray.put(mat)
task = [func_parallel.remote(db_ref) for _ in range(nloop)]
val = ray.get(task)

# Tested with Ray Multiprocessing Pool
# with Pool(ray_remote_args={'num_cpus': 40}) as pool:
#     val = pool.map(func_parallel, [mat for _ in range(nloop)], chunksize=1)

print(val)

Again, this works fine on my laptop, but still consumes over 60GB of VMEM per core on the cluster and is prone to failing when num_cpus exceeds a certain number. The only method I have found to control this ridiculous number is by specifying object_store_memory to the smallest value possible (approx. 80 MB) - which brings VMEM usage down to 9GB per core. RES usage is only 1GB, which seems to be correct for the size of the matrix (100 million elements double precision is just under 1GB).
Still not sure why 9GB is used, but okay I can live with that and it lets me increase num_cpus. Specifying object_store_memory in my original code brings VMEM usage down to 27GB per core. This value oscillates between 5GB to 27GB (as reported by top) and I don't know what stage of the code this corresponds to because my print statements seem to be coming in batches. The oscillation may be due to Ray's retry policy. Again, the job fails when num_cpus exceeds a certain number.
Questions:

Are the jobs failing because of the high VMEM usage?
Why is there such high VMEM usage?
What is going on when using Ray on the cluster as opposed to my laptop? Both run exactly the same code, and while my laptop is decent, it doesn't have 18 * 27GB of free space for this insane VMEM usage.


Are you sure your OOM diagnosis is correct? The error message you are showing is pthread_create failing with EAGAIN, so you ran over the limit of threads you are allowed to create. see also

No, not sure of anything at all. I should have also asked if my fixation on VMEM is even the right way to go because I'm not sure how to interpret the error messages. Is the number of threads created something I can control with Ray? And why is it attempting to create that may threads?

Unfortunately my knowledge of Ray is nonexistent. The link in my previous comment contains some pointers to applicable system limits you can check the values of.

So after more searching, I think the issues of it failing and its VMEM consumption are unrelated. As @teapot418 mentioned above, this is likely a multi-threading issue.
I added the following to my import statements before importing Numpy, Tensorflow, and Ray:
import os
os.environ['OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'
os.environ['OMP_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'
os.environ['RAY_num_server_call_thread'] = '1'
os.environ['TF_NUM_INTEROP_THREADS'] = '1'
os.environ['TF_NUM_INTRAOP_THREADS'] = '1'

And it now runs - still consumes 4TB of VMEM but I don't care anymore.
I'm guessing the issue is due to one or some of the packages enabling multi-threading when I actually want multi-core processing. Someone better will have to explain to me what the difference is and why mixing multi-threading and multi-processing is bad and why I don't encounter this when running on my laptop.
The above was pieced together from the following discussions:

https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/2960
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable
https://discuss.ray.io/t/raylet-openblas/10274/2
https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/739ddfa2290ecbbeeae572a7ab1743055379e3a0/doc/source/example-rl-pong.rst
https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/34724
https://discuss.ray.io/t/why-inter-op-parallelism-threads-and-intra-op-parallelism-threads-dont-work-when-using-ray-train/6720

Just to note that setting the environment variables OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS and OMP_NUM_THREADS alone did not work for the original code, but did work for the simplified code in the post above. My guess is that Numpy uses OpenBLAS to multi-thread operations and was trying to spawn too many threads, thus causing it to fail. The original code does not involve such large matrix multiplications, but does use Tensorflow hence requiring the TF_NUM_INTEROP_THREADS and TF_NUM_INTRAOP_THREADS environment variables to be set to 1 to stop multi-threading.
This does raise the question of, in more complex codes which do involve large matrix multiplication or other operations that Numpy multi-threads and as well as Tensorflow operations, should I use multi-threading or multi-processing? Which is faster? But question for another time... I'm sleepy...

Glad you found the solution: Prevent the libraries (OpenBLAS) from also parallelizing over all available cores. Let me clear up some things, though.
Memory
The question "how much RAM does my program use" has only long and complicated answers (plural). Interpreting the per-process RAM stats is a dark art.
As a first approximation, only ever look at resident (RES). It generally increases as you use more RAM, but it may not decrease again, and other gotchas. It may be easier to estimate RAM usage from inside Python (via Ray, or numpy array sizes).
So either forget all memory stats except for total and resident. (Even free is misleading because of disk caching.) Or, if you want to build your understanding, start by looking up what a TLB is. (Translation look-aside buffer; Warning: this embarks you on a deep-dive into CPU and OS architecture. It's a very central concept, though.)
Threads vs Processes
On Linux at least, a thread is almost the same thing as a process. The difference is not how they use the CPU but whether they start out with shared memory or not.
Python doesn't like sharing its interpreter state - this is the famous GIL (global interpreter lock). To run on multiple cores you have to either start multiple processes (as Ray does) or call a C library (like OpenBLAS) that creates multiple threads to work on a single computation (without the threads calling back into Python code).
To Ray or Not to Ray
Ray tasks should take at least 10ms to 100ms because of the overhead of (potentially) distributing them over network. Local threads (e.g. via OpenBLAS) are much more lightweight, also because they don't run any Python code per thread.
If you have too short Ray tasks, you may be able to batch them (combine into longer tasks). If your tasks are already long enough, try if parallelizing them with OpenBLAS is faster. Parallelizing that way will probably use less memory, because fewer Ray tasks start in parallel, but depends on what you do.
Ray also allows you to reserve e.g. 4 "CPU" resources when you start a task. It will then assume that this task (running in a single Python process) will run 4 threads somehow (e.g. by setting the OpenBLAS number of threads, and spending most time inside OpenBLAS calls).
(If your CPU has hyper-threading, 4 threads means 2 cores. But see above - the CPU doesn't care if you call them threads or processes. But it will care about whether the memory they access is already in its cache. You'll have to check and compare to running the same task single-threaded, to know how much you gained.)
That said, if you can rent a single fat VM with 128 cores (or whatever it is these days) instead of running distributed, then you absolutely should do that. Even if you still use Ray instead of multiprocessing, it will make everything so much simpler and save you a lot of pain.
